# Why does my Samsung Galaxy S21 not rotate the display

Tags: android, screen-rotation, samsung-galaxy, samsung

My Samsung Galaxy S21 has suddenly decided that when I rotate the phone between portrait and landscape mode, it won't rotate its display unless I touch the soft-button which briefly appears.

How can I restore the previous behaviour where it just rotates the display automatically? The problem isn't application specific: it happens whatever I'm displaying. I can't find anything relevant in Settings other than an option to switch off display rotation altogether.

Software version is One UI 5.1 Android 13, and it was recently updated, which might be the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent versions of Android, if `Auto-rotate` is turned off, then the soft button appears. If you turn on `Auto-rotate`, then the screen will rotate automatically. To turn on `Auto-rotate`:

1.Pull down the notification area, you will see that there is an option called `Auto-rotate`.

2. Turn on `Auto-rotate`.

[image]

Comment: On my phone it isn't actually labelled Auto-rotate until I enable it. If it isn't enabled it's labelled "Portrait" or "Landscape" according to the current screen orientation - not very helpful. Anyway thanks for the tip.

Comment: Glad to hear that your problem was solved. Please mark my answer as accepted if it helped you.